# Devise + CanCan, Logged user signing out automatically after update method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan

I'm trying a basic user authorization with CanCan and for some reason the already logged in user, after submitting an update on their profile, devise is signing out.

I can't figure out, why this is happening.

My `ability.rb`

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    can [:welcome, :read, :create, :new], User

    if user.role == 'member'
      can :manage, User, :id => user.id
    end
  end
end
```

And my `update` method from `UsersController`

```
def update
  if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    flash[:success] = "Profile saved!"
    #sign_in @user // tried this with no lucky, it still signing out
    redirect_to @user
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

As you can see, it's pretty basic.

The `flash` message is showing up and the `redirect` also is working as expected.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have forgot to add `before_filter :authenticate_user!` to my `UsersController`

It's now working. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can't find error in your code. I think you need find a problem somewhere else. For example, could you show your `params` hash? And show SQL logs during `@user` updating.